# Setting up configuration settings when writing a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a gem which I would like to work with and without the Rails environment.

I have a `Configuration` class to allow configuration of the gem:

```
module NameChecker
  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :api_key, :log_level

    def initialize
      self.api_key = nil
      self.log_level = 'info'
    end
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration) if block_given?
  end
end
```

This can now be used like so:

```
NameChecker.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'dfskljkf'
end
```

However, I don't seem to be able to access my configuration variables from withing the other classes in my gem. For example, when I configure the gem in my `spec_helper.rb` like so:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
require "name_checker"

NameChecker.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'dfskljkf'
end
```

and reference the configuration from my code:

```
# lib/name_checker/net_checker.rb
module NameChecker
  class NetChecker
    p NameChecker.configuration.api_key
  end
end
```

I get an undefined method error:

```
`<class:NetChecker>': undefined method `api_key' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Here's an article on configuring gems for others who may be interested: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try refactoring to:

```
def self.configuration
  @configuration ||=  Configuration.new
end

def self.configure
  yield(configuration) if block_given?
end
```

Answer (score -2):

The main issue is that you've applied too much indirection. Why don't you just do

```
module NameChecker
  class << self
    attr_accessor :api_key, :log_level
  end
end
```

and be done with it? You could also override the two generated readers right afterwards so that they ensure the presence of the environment that you need...

```
module NameChecker
  class << self
    attr_accessor :api_key, :log_level

    def api_key
      raise "NameChecker really needs is't api_key set to work" unless @api_key
      @api_key
    end

    DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL = 'info'

    def log_level
      @log_level || DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL
    end

  end
end
```

Now, the actual (technical) problem is that you are defining a class called `NetChecker` and while defining it you are trying to print the return value of the `api_key` call on an assumed `Configuration` object (so you are violating the law of Demeter here). This fails, because you are defining `NetChecker` before anyone really has had time to define any configuration. So you are in fact requesting `api_key` before the `configure` method has been called on `NameChecker`, so it has `nil` in it's `configuration` ivar.

My advice would be to remove the overengineering and try again ;-)

Comment: The point of the `Configuration` class is to allow the gem to be configured with a config block. I think that this is the standard way to configure gems. I also just think it is a nice pattern in general. But yeah, what you say about the about the "(technical) problem" makes sense so thanks for that. Finally, in my defense, the Demeter violation was contrived for the sake of question brevity!

Comment: The configure block pattern is entirely optional and comes from Rails, it's not a pattern that everyone adheres to. It's just that Rails has some stuff that _has_ to happen within a configure block when everything is being booted, primarily to prevent Rails from loading too much code (that's why they do it in a special block).

Comment: The problem here isn't over engineering (or violating the law of demeter).  It's an issue of which code is getting executed first.  If you run all of the OP code in a single file, it works fine.  The bug happens when `NameChecker.configuration.api_key` gets executed before the configuration object is populated.