# custom ruby gem not obeying configuration information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a ruby gem that is dependent upon configuration information in the running application.

I'm trying to follow a pattern based on this [this thoughtbot article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/344833329/mygem-configure-block)
or [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584638/setting-up-configuration-settings-when-writing-a-gem)

and I can see that my config/initializer data in the outer app does load, but the problem is, I have code that is dependent upon that initializer that runs before the initializer settings are picked up by the gem.

How can I guarantee that the initialization data is loaded in a timely manner?

Here's my config/initializer code:

```
MbSharedScoreboard.configure do |config|
   config.foo = "bar"
end
```

and here's the where the order I read data in the gem:

```
require "mb_shared_scoreboard/configuration"
require "mb_shared_scoreboard/version"
require "mb_shared_scoreboard/models/service"
require "mb_shared_scoreboard/models/subject"
require "mb_shared_scoreboard/models/foo"

module MbSharedScoreboard

  def self.root
    File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
  end

end
```

and here's the configuration.rb - the first file loaded:

```
module MbSharedScoreboard

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :foo
    def initialize
      @foo = "foo"
    end
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield configuration
    puts "startup configuration: #{self.configuration.to_s}"
  end 
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html),

> In the rare event that your application needs to run some code before
>   Rails itself is loaded, put it above the call to require 'rails/all'
>   in config/application.rb.

You may be able to just get by with including that file there, instead of moving the entire contents.